# What does "the Buckeye" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, word-meaning

> The traditional task of the writer in California has been to write about what it means to be human in a place advertised as paradise. Not the Buckeye or the Empire, not the Can-do or the Show-me, California is the Postlapsarian State. Disappointment has always been the theme of California.

I don't quite understand what the "Buckeye" referring to. I mean, it is connected with California, but what exactly does it imply? I found that the Buckeye might refer to a native or resident of Ohio or a tree/seed. Maybe this word has another meaning.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The alternatives here are all adjectives for particular states

Ohio is the "Buckeye State".

New York is the "Empire State".

Missouri is the "Show-me State".

I don't think there is a "Can-do State".

The author is suggesting "Postlapsarian State" for California, instead of "Golden State".

Comment: https://www.brisbanetimes.com.au/national/queensland/new-number-plate-slogan-can-do-20120331-1w502.html

Comment: Possibly Delaware?

Comment: @CGCampbell Delaware is The First State

Comment: @EthanBolker I am aware of Delaware's motto... suggestion: do a search on Delaware Can and no, I don't mean the playgrounds.

Comment: From googling it seems that rather than being a particular state's appellation, #CanDoStates was a twitter hashtag that trended in 2013, " about states moving ahead on transportation in contrast to a federal government stuck in partisan doldrums." (https://www.nrdc.org/experts/deron-lovaas/can-do-state-maryland-tackles-climate-change)

Comment: Google Books says it could be Georgia. https://www.google.ru/books/edition/Weekly_Compilation_of_Presidential_Docum/0ocl7_W3RpUC?hl=ru&gbpv=1&dq=the+%22can+do+state%22&pg=PA1290&printsec=frontcover

Comment: @Ethan Jolly good and should Rocky just look those up in a list, or could you give him some meaning, perhaps through the origins of those nick-names? As Rocky first Asked, "it is connected with California, but what exactly does it imply?"

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin You can find them if you search for state mottoes. It would take a little more looking to find the source for each one. My last sentence explains the authors intent - none of the examples has anything to do with California.